# What does keras default to when the batch size is larger than the testing set size?

Tags: python, keras

I am running my model and my testing set size is 77.  When I set the batch size to a value larger than the testing set size, my model still runs and there are much less ups and downs in the mean squared error over each epoch.  As I increase the batch size, the model works much more efficiently which is exactly what I want,but I am curious what keras defaults to doing in this scenario.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import read_csv
# load dataset
dataframe = read_csv("new_1501_na_replaced.csv", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:1500]
Y = dataset[:,1500]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(150, input_dim=1500, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(150,kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
# Compile model asking for accuracy, too:
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
model.fit(X, Y, validation_split=0.33,
     batch_size=100,
     epochs=100,
     verbose=1)
score = model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
history = model.fit(X, Y, validation_split=0.33,
     batch_size=500,
     epochs=300,
     verbose=1)
print(score)
# Plot
plt.plot(history.history['mean_squared_error'])
plt.title('mean_squared_error')
plt.show()
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.title('model loss')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by your model works `more efficiently` when you are using larger batch size?

Comment: The mean squared error increases and decreases over epochs but overall goes down.  When I increase the batch size, the mean squared error does not increase as much over epochs.  Eventually when the batch size is large enough, the mean squared error only decreases over epochs until it levels out after a certain point.